# Equivalence of categories

Tags: category-theory

I have an easy question. Could anyone answer only with yes or no? (since I would like to fill in the details myself)

Which of the following sentences are correct?

a) $\textbf{Rel}\simeq\textbf{Rel}^{op}$ 
b) $\textbf{Sets}\simeq\textbf{Sets}^{op}$
c) $\textbf{Pos}\simeq\textbf{Pos}^{op}$

Where Rel is the category of binary relations and Pos is the category of partially ordered sets. I think its yes, no, yes.

Comment: You are right on (b). You are wrong on (c). I am not certain what category you mean by $\mathsf{Rel}$.

Comment: obj(Rel) = sets
arrows(Rel) = binary relations, that is an arbitrary subset $A\times B$ if $A\to B$ is an arrow and compisition is given by
$A\to B\to C \Rightarrow  \{(a,c) \in A\times C \mid \exists b (a,b)\in A\times B, (b,c)\in B\times C \}$
now I just hope that in comments I can write latex code :)

Comment: but thank you a lot, it was a lot of help!

Comment: On (a), you are right.

Comment: Thank you! Have a nice day! I surely will :)

Comment: I made a typo (but cannot yet see the difference). In (c) we have
$P(X)\equiv P(X)^{op}$ where $P(X)$ is the powerset of some set $X$ considered as a poset under inclusion. Does this make any changes? I don't think. But that's just what I feel. Is that correct?

Comment: What you write is true, but doesn't matter for your question. Note that the $\mathrm{op}$ of categories reverses *arrows*, but does nothing to the *objects*.

Comment: okay, thank you again, I felt that it doesn't matter but had to be sure and since I am new to this everything helps :)

Comment: could you give me a hint how to show that the categories in (c) are not isomorphic? what to look for? in Set I looked at initial and terminal objects and in Rel I just wrote everything out and it worked. none of these seems to help here

Comment: Why doesn't your strategy for Set work?

Comment: it worked after all. Thank you for all your supportive comments!